# Submit nested UDTTs to a stored procedure in set based notation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am helping a colleague with a system he has been tasked with where we have a form that has multiple sections and many of those sections can have sub-sections and those 2nd level sub-sections can have (third level) sub-sections themselves.

So, we have multiple `User Defined Table Types`, one that has the top level table structure, then inside of the first section there is a `UDTT` (let's call it subject as it is both sides of the problem in question), then inside of each 'side' we have another `UDTT`, perhaps their `contact information`, `multiple phone numbers` with a type column for each.

And there are n top level sections where up to n of them can have second or even third level `UDTTs` associated with them.

Now, I like using `UDTTs` to import large datasets from some kind of external source (usually a webpage where somebody has uploaded a large `Excel` or `CSV` file), but I have never had the circumstance where I have needed to pass multilevel `UDTTs` to a single stored procedure and I am not even sure how that would work, but in my quest for efficiency I am trying to find a way to do this without a while or for loop.

So... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit UDTT in a nested structure because a UDTT cannot contain a UDTT as a column within it.

However you can solve the problem by flattening the data and using a key field to links the children to the parent. For this you would need 1 parameter per different UDTT structure you are using and then rows within those parameters are linked using the key field to build your hierarchy.

You can then recover you original structure within the stored procedure depending on what actions you wish to take.

Comment: They are linked via Id (foreign key), but I don't see how that helps with the question of 'can I nest UDTTs when submitting a large dataset to a stored procedure?'

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying. Thank you.